# Swift delegate for 2 container views to communicate

Tags: swift2, xcode7.2

In the storyBoard "parent" scene with its parentVC.swift, there are 2 containerVC with embedded segues with their containerVC.swift for each.
In container1, a button action calls the parent custom method.

`(self.parentViewController as? parentVC)?.parentCustomFunc()`

which call container2 custom method.

```
func parentCustomFunc(){
    self.container2.customFunc()
}
```

I read a lot but yet to understand how to apply the use of delegate in this case.
here is my segue block as recorded in parentVC.swift

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let container1VC = segue.destinationViewController as? Cont_1 {
        self.container1 = container1VC  
    } else if let topVC = segue.destinationViewController as? TopVC {
        self.container2 = container2VC  
    }
}
```

Which of the containers should implement the protocol?
 and which of them holds a var to it? How do I get the prepareForSegue to use the delegate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two protocol for each `ChildViewController`.
Maybe like this:

```
protocol Child1Delegate {
     func userTapOnChild1()
}
protocol Child2Delegate {
     func userTapOnChild2()
}
```

And in each controller you can create instance:

```
var delegate: Child2Delegate!
var delegate : Child1Delegate!
```

At Parent controller you implement `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` to assign delegate to child:

```
//You get right identifier of segue you named on storyboard
if segue.identifier == "SegueChild1" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! Child1ViewController
        controller.delegate = self
    }
    if segue.identifier == "SegueChild2" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as!Child2ViewController
        controller.delegate = self
    }
```

And when you do an action from child you can call delegate notify for Parent:

```
@IBAction func child1ButtonIsTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let _delegate = delegate {
        _delegate.userTapOnChild1()
    }
}
```

Parent will implement delegate and do something need:

```
func userTapOnChild1() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Child1", message: "I come from child 1", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Detail you can reference to my demo for this case: [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoDelegateForChildSegue)

Comment: what benefit the delegate method has over the other way?

Comment: It seprate code and will can know what will pass and when. You write above is delegate so I give use delegate